# getLastRealOrderId not working when payment done via payumoney

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

i did payment from payumoney .i have written custom module to notify after order done , below is snippet it work fine for cod but when payment done via payumoney i get error

```
$orderIncrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$orderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId); 
$orderObject->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

Error :

Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on boolean in /xxxt/Model/Observer.php

Answer (score 0):

What observer are you using? If you use `sales_order_place_after` you can try

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
$orderId = $order->getId();
$order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

Comment: i am using checkout_onepage_controller_success_action. i tried you solution but it did now worked